# What is the purpose of the "SHIFT_COORDS" command in Stim?

Tags: error-correction, stim

I have been looking at several circuits being generated by Stim in the literature, e.g. in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.02192.pdf, and I have stumbled upon the operation

`circuit.append_operation("SHIFT_COORDS", [], [0,0,1])`

Can someone explain how this operation works and what is the effect on the circuit? What coordinates are shifted? Also, why is it only placed after detectors?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[`SHIFT_COORDS`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md#SHIFT_COORDS) exists so that detectors declared in a `REPEAT` block can end up with different coordinates from iteration to iteration. Otherwise, when you made a detector error model diagram (or some other thing that uses the coordinates instead of ignoring them), they'd all end up on top of each other.

What [`SHIFT_COORDS`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md#SHIFT_COORDS) does is to accumulate an offset to add to later coordinate data in [`DETECTOR`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md#DETECTOR) and [`QUBIT_COORDS`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md#QUBIT_COORDS) commands.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! May I also ask, what do each of the list arguments following `SHIFT_COORDS` mean?

Comment: @EzequielRodriguezChiacchio Well there's the first coordinate shift, the second coordinate shift, the third coordinate shift, etc